# Is there an equivalent to `http_build_query` for `multipart/form-data` in PHP?

Tags: php, http, multipartform-data

I need to respond to a HTTP request to a PHP script with a collection of files, `multipart/form-data` should be the perfect solution but I cannot find a way to serialize a PHP object/array into it.

In short: Does PHP have and equivalent to the `FormData` available in Javascript?

Comment: You wish to send files and it's content as a response?

Comment: I wish so send multiple blobs in a single http response. The same as you can send multiple blobs in a http request.

Comment: IMO, simply send links for those files in the response. Sending blobs will increase your response time.

Comment: It less than a few kB in total, if multipart/form-data is not an option I will just base64 encode them.

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is from client to server and not vice-versa. Try your case with base64 and then you can ask a more focussed question.

Comment: multipart/form-data is a content-type it should work with any http body, do browsers lack support for it in responses?

Comment: I have barely ever seen anyone doing that. [`This`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/formData) doc might be relevant. IMO, I would have simply sent links to those files and then sending raw data when the individual image file link is hit.